# Transformable attribute on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

> I have stored dictionary in the transformable attribute.I want to know

How  to get single data from it?**

```
NSFetchRequest  *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] 
initWithEntityName:@"MemberProfile"];
NSSortDescriptor *ordering = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:
[member.member_Profile objectForKey:"@order"] ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray 
 arrayWithObjects:ordering,nil]];
NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext 
executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:Nil];
self.masterList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
```

Comment: Could you post the code of whatever you have tried until now?

Comment: i want to get data based on the order key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import NSManagedObject(InstallProject) and fetch one object like this,

```
-(InstallProject *)readSelectedInstall:(NSString *)projIDString
{
NSArray *fetchedObjects;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"InstallProject"  inManagedObjectContext: context];
[fetch setEntity:entityDescription];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY ProjID contains[cd] %@)",projIDString]];
NSError * error = nil;
fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];

if([fetchedObjects count] == 1)
return [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
else
return nil;  
}
```

Comment: here you gave the search string yourself to get the data from transformable attribute.my problem is the search string also located in transformable attribute.first i need to get it from transformable attribute in order to process further..